# Zabbix query every item at the same time (initially)

Tags: typo3, zabbix, zabbix-api

I am currently building monitoring for my 20 TYPO3 hosts with zabbix. For this, I have a templates that queries things like TYPO3 version etc. These items have a delay of 1 day. This means when I upload a template because I did some changes, I have to wait an entire day to see if it worked.

Is there something like a button to trigger every single request?

Comment: In the web interface in host configuration in an item configuration, there is literally "Execute" and "Test" which allow testing and getting the value. You can also select multiple items, and execute them all. I think it may not have been there in some previous zabbix versions, but in zabbix 5.2 it's there

Comment: Yes, this gives me "request sent". But that doesn't change anything in the overview, no values update in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

There is a TYPO3 extension as Zabbix client. Maybe this can help you:

- TYPO3 Extension Repository: [zabbix_client](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/zabbix_client)
- GitHub: [wapplersystems/zabbix_client](https://github.com/svewap/zabbix_client)